# Get SMS Access in KitKat

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

I have written an SMS App which writes into the SMS storage. This always worked until Andorid 4.4 KitKat. I then read that there is always 1 main SMS App.
Now I want to ask the user if he wants to use my App as main App before I do my things and ask to change back after I'm done with writing to the storage.

So first I want a dialog like this to let me write:

[image]

And then I want to change it back to the one the user had before.

The code I have now is not working:

```
String defaultSmsApp = null;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        defaultSmsApp = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(myContext);

        final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
        Log.e("SMS Faker", "myPackageName=" + myPackageName);
        Log.e("SMS Faker", "defaultSmsApp=" + defaultSmsApp);
        if (!defaultSmsApp.equals(myPackageName)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, myContext.getPackageName());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements for an application to be SMS app are

```
   Implement SMS_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast receiver with BROADCAST_SMS permission.

   Implement WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast receiver with BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH permission.

   Implement RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE intent and should support smsto Uri scheme and require SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE permission.

   Implement ACTION_SENDTO intent support smsto Uri scheme.
```

So you need your manifest to be something like below with all the above fields mandatory. Only then will your **Intent intent = new Intent(Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);** work

```
  <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="SmsReciever"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="MmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="RespondService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```